# How to find the maximum row and column WITHOUT reading all data?

Tags: c#, .net, google-sheets-api

Using C# [.Net Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/dotnet).

I am new to the API, so I may have missed it in the docs - but how do you find out the maximum row and column that contain a value without reading all the data in the sheet?

For example, if a sheet contains multiple values and the "last" cell in the sheet with a value is at C139 (no cells in the rows following have a value and no cells in any column after C have a value), then the maximum row would be 139 and the maximum column would be 2 (zero based) or 3 (one based).

I tried sheet.Properties.GridProperties.RowCount -- but that gives the TOTAL number of rows in the sheet (whether the cells have values or not).

Same goes for sheet.Properties.GridProperties.ColumnCount -- gives the TOTAL number of columns in the sheet (whether the cells have values or not).

Any links or ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to know the last row of data in your Sheet. In that case, you can use a simple [`GET`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get) with a full range. For example let's assume that your Sheet only has two columns, in that case you can set up the range like `A1:B`. That range will include the full two columns, but the get will only get as far as the data goes. At this step you already have an array filled with your data range, so you only have to count the array index of the last element in order to know the last row value. If you don't know how many columns your Sheet have, you only have to modify the range in a similar way as before (i.e. `A1:Z`). Please ask me any doubts about this approach.

Comment: Thanks for the comment -- but the original question did ask "without reading all the data in the sheet" --  I was hoping there would be an API call that could be made to tell me the maximum row and column, WITHOUT reading ALL of the sheet data.   I seem to recall something being available in Google App Script -- but I am using the .Net API.

Comment: Thank you for your appreciation. You are right, on Apps Script you could use [`Range.getLastRow()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow)/[`Range.getLastColumn()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastcolumn) to get the last row/column. My answer works for the Sheets API, but you could use the [Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/dotnet) to run a script that gets you the last row/column on response. Would that be a valid solution for you?

Comment: Thanks again -- Unfortunately, for this project, I am tied to the .Net API exclusively and have yet to find the equivalent methods that exist in Apps Script.